# Useless rules and nonterminals in Bison grammar

Tags: c++, grammar, bison, yacc

I have the following Bison file describing my scripting language grammar:

```
%error-verbose
%{
#include "node.h"
NBlock *programBlock;

#define YYDEBUG 1

extern int yylex();
void yyerror(const char *) { printf("Error: %s\n", s); }
%}

%union {
    Node *node;
    NBlock *block;
    NBody *body;
    NHeader *header;
    NExpression *expression;
    NStatement *statement;
    NIdentifier *identifier;
    NVariableDeclaration *variableDeclaration;
    NDoWhileStatement *doWhileStatement;
    NWhileStatement *whileStatement;
    NIfStatement *ifStatement;
    NForStatement *forStatement;
    std::vector<NVariableDeclaration*> *variableDeclarations;
    std::vector<NExpression*> *expressions;
    std::vector<NStatement*> *statements;
    std:string *string;
    int token;
}


%token <string> TIDENTIFIER TINTEGER TDOUBLE
%token <token> TCEQ TCNE TCLT TCLE TCGT TCGE TEQUAL
%token <token> TLPAREN TRPAREN TLBRACE TRBRACE TCOMMA TDOT
%token <token> TPLUS TMINUS TMUL TDIV TDO TDOUBLE_TYPE TINT_TYPE
%token <token> TELSE TFOR TIF TSEMICOLON TTHEN TWHILE

%type <expression> expression term factor
%type <block> program body header tail statements
%type <statement> statement forStatement ifStatement doWhileStatement whileStatement variableDeclaration
%type <token> comparison
%type <string> identifier_type


%left TPLUS TMINUS
%left TMUL TDIV

%start program

%%

program:                TLBRACE body TRBRACE { printf("Reduce body to program\n"); }
                        ;

body:                   header TLBRACE block TRBRACE tail { printf("Reduce header block tail to body\n"); }
                        ;

header:                 TLBRACE variableDeclarations TRBRACE { printf("Reduce variableDeclarations to header\n"); }
                        | TLBRACE TRBRACE { printf("Reduce empty to header\n"); }
                        ;

variableDeclarations:   variableDeclaration TSEMICOLON { printf("Reduce variable declaration to header\n"); }
                        | variableDeclarations variableDeclaration TSEMICOLON { printf("Reduce variable declaration list to header\n"); }
                        ;

tail:                   TLBRACE statements TRBRACE { printf("reduce statement list to tail\n"); }
                        | TLBRACE TRBRACE { printf("Reduce empty to tal\n"); }
                        ;                   

statements:             statement TSEMICOLON { printf("Reduce statement to statement list\n"); }
                        | statements statement TSEMICOLON { printf("Reduce statement list to statement list\n"); }
                        ;

statement:              ifStatement { printf("Reduce if to statement\n"); };
                        | forStatement { printf("Reduce for to statement\n"); };
                        | doWhileStatement { printf("Reduce doWhile to statement\n"); };
                        | whileStatement { printf("reduce while to statement\n"); }
                        | expression { printf("Reduce expression to statement\n"); };
                        ;

forStatement:           TFOR TLPAREN expression TSEMICOLON expression TSEMICOLON expression TRPAREN block { printf("Reduce for to for statement\n"); }
                        ;


ifStatement:            TIF expression TTHEN block { printf("Reduce if to if statement\n"); }
                        | TIF expression block TELSE block { printf("Reduce ifelse to if statement\n"); }
                        ;

doWhileStatement:       TDO block TWHILE expression { printf("reduce dowhile to while statement\n"); }
                        ;

whileStatement:         TWHILE block expression { printf("Reduce while to while statement\n"); }
                        ;

block:                  TLBRACE statements TRBRACE { printf("Reduce statement list to block\n"); }
                        | TLBRACE TRBRACE { printf("Reduce empty to block\n"); }
                        ;

variableDeclaration:    identifier_type TIDENTIFIER { printf("reduce uninitialized identifier to variable declaration\n"); }
                        | identifier_type TIDENTIFIER TEQUAL expression { printf("Reduce initialized identifier to variable declaration\n"); }
                        ;

identifier_type:        TINT_TYPE { printf("Reduce int to identifier type\n"); }
                        | TDOUBLE_TYPE { printf("Reduce double to identifier type\n"); }
                        | { printf("Reduce empty to identifier type\n"); }
                        ;



expression:             TIDENTIFIER TEQUAL expression { printf("Reduce assignment to expression\n"); }
                        | TIDENTIFIER { printf("reduce identifier to expression\n"); }
                        | expression comparison expression { printf("Reduce comparison to expression\n"); }
                        | TLPAREN expression TRPAREN { printf("Reduce nested expression to expression\n"); }
                        | expression TPLUS term { printf("Reduce addition to expression\n"); }
                        | expression  TMINUS term { printf("Reduce subtraction to expression\n"); }
                        | term { printf("Reduce term to expresson\n"); }
                        | factor { printf("Reduce factor to expression\n"); }
                        ;

term:                   term TMUL factor { printf("Reduce multiplication to term\n"); }
                        | term TDIV factor { printf("Reduce division to term\n"); }
                        ;

factor:                 TIDENTIFIER { printf("Reduce identifier to factor\n"); }
                        | TINTEGER { printf("Reduce integer to numeric\n"); }
                        | TDOUBLE { printf("Reduce double to numeric\n"); }
                        ;

comparison:             TCEQ { printf("Reduce eq to comparison\n"); }
                        | TCNE { printf("Reduce ne to comparison\n"); }
                        | TCLT { printf("Reduce lt to comparison\n"); }
                        | TCLE { printf("Reduce le to comparison\n"); }
                        | TCGT { printf("reduce gt to comparison\n"); }
                        | TCGE { printf("Reduce ge to comparison\n"); }
                        | TPLUS { printf("Reduce plus to comparison\n"); }
                        | TMINUS { printf("Reduce minus to comparison\n"); }
                        | TMUL { printf("Reduce mul to comparison\n"); }
                        | TDIV { printf("Reduce div to comparison\n"); }
                        ;
```

I really don't understand why I am getting errors related to useless nonterminals and useless rules.

Running the command:

```
bison -d -o parser.cpp parser.y
```

I get the following errors:

```
$ bison -d -o parser.cpp parser.y
parser.y: attention: 1 nonterminal useless in grammar
parser.y: attention: 5 rules useless in grammar
parser.y:52.31-34: attention: nonterminal useless in grammar: term
parser.y:135.51-118: attention: rule useless in grammar: expression: expression TPLUS term
parser.y:136.51-123: attention: rule useless in grammar: expression: expression TMINUS term
parser.y:137.51-96: attention: rule useless in grammar: expression: term
parser.y:141.41-103: attention: rule useless in grammar: term: term TMUL factor
parser.y:142.51-107: attention: rule useless in grammar: term: term TDIV factor
parser.y: conflicts: 20 shift/reduce, 14 reduce/reduce
parser.y:145.41-96: attention: rule useless in parser due to conflicts: factor: TIDENTIFIER
```

Comment: I think the useless rules/nonterminals are just a consequence of the conflicts you have. Once you've fixed those I would expect them to go away. Looks at least that you need some more operator precedence defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the conflict is that the parser will not know which rule to chose when it finds a TIDENTIFIER. The reason is that

`TIDENTIFIER` can be reduced to `expression`
`factor` can be reduced to `expression`
`TIDENTIFIER` can be reduced to `factor`

So when the parser get an identifier it can go two ways to reach an expression.

```
TIDENTIFIER -> expression  
TIDENTIFIER -> factor -> expression
```

I thin in your case you can safely remove `TIDENTIFIER` from factor since `factor` is reduced to **ONLY** `expression` anyway.

**However a more proper way (at least for most common languages)** might be to keep `TIDENTIFIER` in `factor` and handle the rest in `statement`. For example `TIDENTIFIER ASSIGN expression` can be a valid `statement`.

BTW your `statement` includes `expression`. Which is proably not what you intended. `statement` should always be different from `expression` (after all that's why you need two rules).

I think you should check for cases like that. If you have a rule using another rule only (without any other tokens or other rules) then it is probably wrong. *Wrong in a sense that it is not what you intended*.

Comment: I fixed the useless rules and nonterminals. I still have to fix 8 shift/reduce conflicts in one single state. I'm going to ask for help with another different question anyway. Tanks @stardust_